# How can I fix error importing numpy in a Jupyter notebook on M1 mac?

Tags: python, macos, numpy, apple-m1

I tried to import numpy in a Jupyter notebook file but it showed the following error (it's completely normal if I import numpy in a python file):

```bash
File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py:16
     13         _missing_dependencies.append(f"{_dependency}: {_e}")
     15 if _missing_dependencies:
---> 16     raise ImportError(
     17         "Unable to import required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(_missing_dependencies)
     18     )
     19 del _hard_dependencies, _dependency, _missing_dependencies
     21 # numpy compat

ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.
...
and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so' (no such file)
```

Comment: The message suggests it's trying to run the Intel version.  As a temporary solution, have you considered using Rosetta 2 and the Intel version of Python?

Comment: @tresf seems like it doesn't have an option to open Vscode through Rosetta 2. What should I do?

Comment: Maybe reinstall numpy and pandas in the notebook? (using pip)

Comment: @bento: Although I do not use VSCode for this purpose and have not tested this, this article may help: https://dev.to/markwitt_me/creating-a-custom-vscode-terminal-profile-for-using-rosetta-on-an-m1-mac-apple-silicon-2gb2